# how can i replace NaN in a row with values in another row in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

dataset :

[image]

I need to replace NaN values in the column "actual price" with column values in "price"

Comment: Can you add the data instead of the image please?

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas with df as your dataframe :

```
df.actual_price.fillna(df.price, inplace=True)
```

This will replace all `NaN` values in the column `actual_price` with respective values from the price column.